# Azure VNet: Connect to VM using custom jump server

Tags: azure, rdp, azure-vm, vnet

I have created a virtual network on Microsoft azure; I want to attach a jump server that will allow the users to connect to VM without exposing them publicly

The functionalities I need from my jump server are as follows:

1. The server should allow users to authenticate using the Azure active directory
2. User session should timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity.
3. The server should call a rest API when a user tries to connect and after the session has ended: After successful authentication, when the user attempts to initiate the session, API should be called, which will start the VM; and when the session end, API will deallocate the VM.

Can anyone please help me understand if there is any software that can be used to achieve these features

Comment: Where are you users? On a corporate network? Do you have a VPN set up from from the on-premises corporate to a VNET in Azure? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't have any VPN, so users can log in from anywhere, but only Jump Server will be assigned public IP, so they can only connect to jump server, and jump server will redirect the initiate the RDP session between the users. I have tried to look for the solution in apache guacamole, windows rds and myrtille, but either they don't have api, session timeout or webhook option. So, I'm confused, how can this be achieved

Comment: Any reason you don’t just use log analytics to audit user login?  You could add a script like this to fire a web API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/logon-trigger-example--scripting-

Comment: Thanks for sharing about Windows task Scheduler. I require starting the VM when the user is authenticated and deallocating the VM once the session has ended. It seems that TaskScheduler is a Windows service. Will it be possible to start and deallocate the VM?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that requirement?

Comment: Oh I see it is laready buried in there, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Bastion service allows you to connect to a VM in Azure without the need of exposing a public IP address to that server.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview

> Azure Bastion is a service you deploy that lets you connect to a
> virtual machine using your browser and the Azure portal. The Azure
> Bastion service is a fully platform-managed PaaS service that you
> provision inside your virtual network. It provides secure and seamless
> RDP/SSH connectivity to your virtual machines directly from the Azure
> portal over TLS. When you connect via Azure Bastion, your virtual
> machines do not need a public IP address, agent, or special client
> software.

Starting and stopping the VM would be done through the portal